# Vectors in Normed Space Must Have Finite Length?

Tags: vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I have assumed this to be the case, and consequently this is why one looks at *convergent sequences* of vectors in normed, Banach, and Hilbert spaces.

But, I've never seen this listed explicitly as an axiom of a normed space.

(I thought it might perhaps be inferred from a requirement for homogeneity of the norm,, i.e. $||\alpha.v|| = |\alpha|.||v||$ where $\alpha $ is (finite) scalar: but this still works  if $||v||$ is infinite.)

**Any feedback would be appreciated.**

Comment: Normally, a norm is defined as a map $\left\|\cdot\right\|:V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ satisfying certain properties, but $\infty\notin \mathbb{R}^+$, hence the length of each vector is finite by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the definition of a norm on wikipedia (which matches the definitions I encountered in textbooks) (link [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)))

> if $V$ is a vector space, then a norm is a function $\rho: V\to \mathbb R$ that satisfies certain properties

so it is quite explicitly stated that the norm of every vector is a *real number*, thus *finite*.

Comment: Ah yes, quite obvious now mention it. Thanks.